# lockscreen on web page

Tags: html, lockscreen

I want to create fancy lock screen on my web portal. For javascript and timer I used https://github.com/maxfierke/jquery-sessionTimeout-bootstrap plugin. I got idea from many bootstrap admin templates like: http://webapplayers.com/inspinia_admin-v1.2/lockscreen.html.

If I use only javascript, page will be displayed (redirected), but, I can easy back on previous page. Maybe I need expand my DB table with new column for detecting lock screen or enough create a cookie with some parameters.

Any idea, what is the best way to solve it?

Comment: Have a look at the [`sleep`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) function. You can use it with your php session.